# Android Layout AutoCompleteTextView NullPointerException Workaround

Tags: layout, android, nullpointerexception, autocompletetextview

I'm working in with the Android SDK 2.0 / Galileo / ADT 0.9.4 (latest to date).
Against Android 1.5 API layer.

If I go to the layout editor and add an AutoCompleteTextView the screen immediately gives me a NullPointerException.

Does anyone have a documented workaround for this problem?

I can't seem to find one.
This is obviously a bug in the Android SDK. (It's been filed anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a limitation of the layout editor. Get your layout right with EditText and then change them to AutoCompleteTextView when you are done editing your layout.